# LaTeX CV- Deedy Resume: How to compile and get pdf for Deedy Resume MacFonts?

Tags: xetex, cv, deedy-resume

So I wanted to use the [MacFonts](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume/tree/master/MacFonts) version of [Deedy Resume](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume), I can't find any option to do that on [Overleaf](https://overleaf.com) , however I tried and installed [TeXstudio](https://www.texstudio.org) to do so, Since being a rookie, I am having hard time to get a MacFont version like this

[image]

How can I proceed and get that in TeXstudio or TexMaker? I have no idea how to use texmaker, save file and generate pdf for the same. Since the file extensions are of `xtx`, and `cls`. I can't do a simple things. Please help me out how can I edit and generate the pdf for the resume like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deedydas/Deedy-Resume/master/MacFonts/sample-image.png)
P.S - I need MacFonts

Comment: TeXstudio needs the LaTeX binary files I belive, as [TexLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) provides. Then it should be as easy as opening the directory and compiling the main tex file.

Comment: The `.xtx` file should not be a problem, as it has the same syntax as any other `.tex` files as far as I can see. The `.cls` file is just for styling the document, and uses the same syntax as other `.tex` files.

Comment: It isn't working out. I don't know how to proceed

Comment: So you have TexLive installed? It should take a long time, usually takes a few hours for me.. What is the errors when you try to compile the document? You need to provide some more descriptive information.

Comment: I am a noobe and hence no idea about how to work offline on this I've just worked on overleaf and edited the pre defined things. Now when I am trying to update in MacOs (For macfonts) I don't know how to do that. Can you please tell me the entire procedure to do that in **TexMaker**? I'll be thankful to you.

Comment: You are using a Mac right? or else you will need to find the relevant fonts and install them.

Comment: I have the same problems with TeXStudio, my document is `deedy-resume.cls` and `cv_12.tex` too... but I cant compile my document. D o I have to install all packages on my TeXStudio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run/compile a `.tex` document on a computere native instead of on online services such as Overleaf you need two things:

1. A IDE (Integrated development environment) or a text editor.

   - [Full list over popular editors at this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).
   - TeXstudio is an IDE and will work fine.
   - You could even use Windows notepad, it does not matter as you are only writing pure text.
2. A compiler. A compiler takes the code, images and text and converts it to your chosen format (`PDF`, `DVI`, `HTML`, etc).

   - There are several compilers such as `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`, etc. But the most common and popular one is `pdflatex`. Usually the standard/pre-chosen choosen in your IDE.
   - The easiest way to obtain the compilers is to download and install packages of the latex environment. There are two popular choices that include everthing you need to compile a basic document: [MiKTeX link](https://miktex.org/) and [TeX Live link](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) (I personally prefer TeX Live as it includes ALL packages for `\usepackage{}` that you will probably ever use).

So you install both the editor (which you say you have) and a compiler package such as Tex Live. When that is done and you have both of the necessary things installed so you can try to compile your document in TeXstudio ([TeXstudio user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html)). To compile the document there should be a `play/arrow` button as in the image belove.

[image: TeXstudio]

If this does not work you look at the `messages` or `log` tabs to find out what went wrong. It will tell you if the compiler is not set up or if there is something wrong with your syntax.

If you chose a text editor to write/code your document you would have to use the terminal to compile your document, so if you are new to this sort of things stick to a IDE as TeXstudio.

Comment: Thank you @Niklas I am getting this [error](https://imgur.com/a/64cRExO), Please help me how to proceed further. The log is [here](https://pastebin.com/AbyaGEU0)

Comment: It worked finally! My problem got resolved by installing MikTex and later the error I was getting got resolved by having all the required files in the directory. Special Thanks to @Niklas for helping me out :)